# Build / project type - Microsoft.NET.Sdk

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, dotnet-sdk

Using try-convert on projects to the new project type/build system [Microsoft.NET.Sdk].
But I am getting issues with how it resolves dependencies i.e. we still have a few places referencing the old WPF toolkit & it has namespace collision with the standard libraries for VisualStateManager. Previously we solved it with alias the reference in the local project but now it seems to be spreading to other projects referencing that project.

How can this be solved gracefully using the existing build system.

Answer (score 0):

Transitive dependencies:
https://curia.me/net-core-transitive-references-and-how-to-block-them
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/11803

```
<PropertyGroup>            
<DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>
</PropertyGroup>
  <!--
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <PackageReference>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <ProjectReference>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  -->
```